# What are the energy requirements to reach Earth orbit and Mars orbit assuming no efficiency losses?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, energy, calculation

Suppose some magic propulsion method exists which directly converts electricity into kinetic energy. And its efficiency is 100%. And its weight is 0.

What is a way to calculate the energy requirements for a 1kg weight to reach Earth orbit and Mars orbit (both when orbital trajectories are favorable and when they aren't)?

Comment: You can calculate the difference in orbital energy between the object sitting at the surface (at apogee of a very suborbital trajectory with perigee way down in the core) and the target orbit, but just converting some other form of energy into kinetic energy breaks conservation of momentum, which is no less fundamental than conservation of energy.

Comment: I think the 2nd sentence is fine and answering it does not require the first sentence. Just ask "What energy is gained." Energy per kg is sometimes called reduced energy and is just $$\frac{1}{2} v^2 - \frac{GM}{r}$$ (kinetic + potential) where $M$ is the mass of whatever you are currently orbiting. It gets tricky when you transition from bound to unbound from Earth and start considering the heliocentric velocity and distance from the Sun.

Comment: Not sure this is answerable. Using delta-v will tell how much acceleration a given payload will need to get from orbit A to orbit B - but not how much fuel it has to carry that begins as "payload" but gets used along the way. It cannot tell us how efficient that fuel use can be.